# Force browser to download the video instead opening in html

Tags: javascript, php

[link](https://r3---sn-fapo3ox25a-3uhl.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?mn=sn-fapo3ox25a-3uhl&mm=31&id=o-ALLyHMODFlHOKLmejy__bT3j3IkmFCfFfXrFA2tfi3Eu&mv=m&mt=1506092234&ms=au&ei=RyXFWeKkKI_cogOH0LGgAg&ip=27.34.20.130&pl=23&ratebypass=yes&itag=43&expire=1506113959&signature=181F79F586561BF575B8AE2A3CEE6B7FC08A8248.C3D2E00EAA301402CF19CD484F79974DC7F9BDA9&key=yt6&gir=yes&dur=0.000&source=youtube&lmt=1490104605623196&requiressl=yes&initcwndbps=718750&ipbits=0&sparams=clen%2Cdur%2Cei%2Cgir%2Cid%2Cinitcwndbps%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Clmt%2Cmime%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cpcm2cms%2Cpl%2Cratebypass%2Crequiressl%2Csource%2Cexpire&clen=8147748&pcm2cms=yes&mime=video%2Fwebm)

Above is the download link.... 
I am making a downloading site but the download link opens in the browser rather than downloading.
I also tried  but not working !!!! how can I make this downloadable for my site!

PS: It can be saved as if right clicked..

Comment: zip the video and add to a link a href='video.zip' ...

Comment: that would mean he has to first download the video to his server. the like is a google one

Comment: Send it it a PHP script, serve a mime type (octet-stream i think) that requires download, then read the file and serve the contents to them.

Comment: theres a download property of href links now, not fully supported, see above link

Comment: html's `download` attribute wont work because it will be CORS enabled resource .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would pipe the file through php:

```
$filename= 'somefile.gif';
$url = 'https://somesite.tld'.$filename;
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary"); 
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\""); 
echo readfile($url);
```

Try this with your own url and filename. Navigating to this php-script in the browser and your file will be downloaded.

Comment: you might even want to add `header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `curl` to download the link to your server first , then you can download from your server.

**Code Download file from Server link**

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION,3);

$source = "https://r3---sn-h557snlz.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?id=o-ALLyHMODFlHOKLmejy__bT3j3IkmFCfFfXrFA2tfi3Eu&ei=RyXFWeKkKI_cogOH0LGgAg&ip=27.34.20.130&pl=21&ratebypass=yes&itag=43&expire=1506113959&signature=6AB44626DF3DC5CC517D1B0C7DC1ACF27CC7B6A7.2BC18ED29E93C2B8150031A26E88992AB0EBDA1E&key=cms1&gir=yes&dur=0.000&source=youtube&lmt=1490104605623196&requiressl=yes&ipbits=0&sparams=clen,dur,ei,expire,gir,id,initcwndbps,ip,ipbits,ipbypass,itag,lmt,mime,mip,mm,mn,ms,mv,pcm2cms,pl,ratebypass,requiressl,source&clen=8147748&mime=video%2Fwebm&req_id=7d993d5e8d1aa3ee&redirect_counter=2&fexp=23702512&cms_redirect=yes&ipbypass=yes&mip=171.76.76.26&mm=30&mn=sn-h557snlz&ms=nxu&mt=1506094130&mv=m";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $source);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION,3);
$data = curl_exec ($ch);
$error = curl_error($ch); 
curl_close ($ch);

$destination = "/path/to/public/file.webm";
$file = fopen($destination, "w+");
fputs($file, $data);
fclose($file);
```

After your html can contain as follows

```
<a href="/file.webm" download>
  Download video
</a>
```